# How can i run curl on command line?

Tags: php, apache, curl, composer-php

I was trying to download composer from [here](http://getcomposer.org/download/). But I dont know how to Run this in my terminal to get the latest Composer version:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I have installed WAMP and cURL is enabled

Comment: install cURL. open the command prompt. paste the command you gave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Curl commands from Windows Console](http://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console)

Comment: This is meant to be executed in a shell like `bash`. Since your on windows you only have `cmd.exe` which doesn't support pipes and you need to install `curl` for the command line. You could save the file on `https://getcomposer.org/installer` change into the directory where you saved it using the `cd` command in `cmd.exe` and execute `php the-file-youve-donwloaded.php`.

Comment: @Gordon i am getting "curl is not recognized as an internal ..." error . From which which path i have to run curl command?

Comment: @Serjas from the path to which you installed it unless you added that path to your PATH environment variable in which case you can run it from everywhere

Comment: @Serjas you first need to install curl for windows. It also needs to be inside of the `%PATH%` variable

Comment: @Mogria thanks, your previous comment also worked for me. I have already enabled curl in localhost. Do i need to install another curl for windows?

Comment: @Serjas yes, if you want to do it using curl. But this site http://getcomposer.org/download/ proposes to use `php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"` if don't have curl installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from the comments , I got it working by following this steps

1. Downloaded Win32 - Generic -> Win32 2000/XP zip file from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
2. extracted to a folder inside c:\windows\system32\
3. now i can run 'curl' command from windows command prompt (cmd.exe)